# Zend_Pdf - load utf-8 pdf document

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

I'm currently trying to load a PDF document using the `Zend_Pdf::load($filename)` method and I'm getting

```
Error occured while 'xxx.pdf' file reading.
```

So I see in Zend_Pdf_Parser::_construct there is this block

```
while ($byteCount > 0 && !feof($pdfFile)) {
   $nextBlock = fread($pdfFile, $byteCount);
   if ($nextBlock === false) {
        require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Pdf_Exception( "Error occured while '$source' file reading." );
   }
   $data .= $nextBlock;
   $byteCount -= strlen($nextBlock);
}
if ($byteCount != 0) {
   require_once 'Zend/Pdf/Exception.php';
   throw new Zend_Pdf_Exception( "Error occured while '$source' file reading." );
}
```

After debugging, I can tell that `strlen($nextBlock)` is not returning the right value (based on `$nextBlock = fread($pdfFile, $byteCount);` )
If I use `mb_strlen($nextBlock,'8bit')` instead this block passes right. Now I'm getting another error

```
Pdf file syntax error. 'startxref' keyword expected
```

So now I look into Zend_Pdf_StringParser:readLexeme() and I can see that again there is a problem with singlebyte vs. multibyte string functions (strlen etc.)

So does anybody have a clue what's going on with Zend_Pdf, if this is general bug or I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I never used Zend_PDF because it has very few potential. I advise you to integrate into your project [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error and it turned out to be a bug in Zend Guard. Apparently my version of the PHP encoder turns the ASCII NP form feed character (\f) inside string literals into the backslash (\) **and** the f characters (\\f).

The obfuscated version of

```
print bin2hex("\f");
```

outputs

```
5c66
```

instead of the expected

```
0c
```

This behavior causes Zend_Pdf_StringParser to parse 'startxre' instead of 'startxref' in readLexeme, causing the error you described.

If you are using a different version of the encoder or no encoder at all, then this may not be the cause of the problem (try reproducing it on a different PHP version).